# Adding content to wordpress post with shortcode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am looking to add something like this http://jsfiddle.net/theimaginative/gA63t/ to a wordpress post. I have been trying to create a shortcode to insert this into a post but have been struggling with it. I can get a basic short code to work to add text just using a basic function but after searching google for hours I can't figure out how to have html and javascript as a part of the short code content.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
<div id="sliderone">
<div id="nav">
    <div id="navone" style="text-align: center;">This is a clickable title</div>
</div>
<div id="title"></div>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

$('#navone').click(function () {
$('#title').html("<img src='http://placehold.it/350x350' alt='' />");
$('#sliderone').animate({
height: '450'
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign multi-line strings to a variable using PHP's [HEREDOC syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

It would look something like this.

```
function addClickableTile(){

$content = <<<HEREDOC

<div id="sliderone">
<div id="nav">
    <div id="navone" style="text-align: center;">This is a clickable title</div>
</div>
<div id="title"></div>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

$('#navone').click(function () {
$('#title').html("<img src='http://placehold.it/350x350' alt='' />");
$('#sliderone').animate({
height: '450'
});
});

</script>

HEREDOC;

return $content;

}

add_shortcode('addClickableTile','addClickableTile');
```

Comment: For all options, OP should refer to the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

Comment: Yes, the code above just dumps a string onto the page, it doesn't accept any arguments.